# SSL is installed successfully but the URL still showing not secure in AWS ec2 instance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, .htaccess, https, url-rewriting

I have successfully installed SSL in aws server. I can see that HTTPS is in the URL. I am using WordPress and I have updated the  URL https://www.example.com in the database. I am using the below code in the htaccess but still, I am getting

[image]

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.in%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It might be a problem with your SSL certificate. If you click the "Advanced..." button, you should be able to find out if your certificate is somehow invalid.

Comment: @Brian, No there is no issue with SSL certificate.